# How do I parent a single bone from a rigify metarig to a cube without it parenting the whole metarig?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent, rigify

I'd like to parent a single bone within a Rigify human full skeleton metarig to a corresponding cube [which contains animation information], however I can't select a single bone for parenting without selecting the whole skeleton. Is it not possible to parent individual bones within a metarig?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't think you can parent an individual bone to a mesh object. You can constrain it tho, so maybe that could solve your problem.

Comment: thanks - that worked!